# Is the sentence "You have been short-listed for next phase of the interview." correct?

Tags: grammar

I want to communicate to a candidate that he has been shortlisted. Should I say that "You have been short-listed" or "You are short-listed"?

Comment: Both would work fine here.

Comment: You can use either "You are..." or "You have been..." as @Stockfish says but you need another definite article before "next phase" so that the sentence reads "You are (or have been) shortlisted for _the_ next phase of the interview". In fact 'stage of the interview" is more usual than "phase" in my experience and the whole sentence can be re-written more compactly as "You have been (or are) short-listed for the next interview stage".